# Problem with XML and HTTParty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby, curl

I've just started using HTTParty, and i've encountered a problem in the way it builds the Hash from the XML replied by the server.

If i setup the following Builder template on the server:

```
xml.thunt :sendSubscriptionResult, :"xmlns:thunt" => "http://example.com/thunt", :status => @status
```

everything works well, i.e. the Hash built by HTTParty matches the XML generated by Builder, (the latter can be observed by making the same request via curl):

**curl Request**

```
curl -s -H "Accept: text/xml" -d "xml=`cat vendor/testxml/requests/sendsubscription.xml`" $SERVER/${name}
```

**Reply as seen by curl**

```
    '<thunt:sendSubscriptionResult xmlns:thunt="http://example.com/thunt" status="alreadySubscribed" />'
```

**HTTParty request**

```
TreasureHunt.post('/sendsubscription', :query => { :xml => sub } )
```

**Reply in HTTParty**

```
{"thunt:sendSubscriptionResult"=>{"status"=>"alreadySubscribed", "xmlns:thunt"=>"http://example.com/thunt"}}
```

---

**But**, if in the Builder i specify that i want the sendSubscriptionResult element to have a text node:

```
xml.thunt :sendSubscriptionResult, "Hello, World", :"xmlns:thunt" => "http://example.com/thunt", :status => @status
```

(note the "Hello, World" addition) the two tools suddenly disagree.

**curl**

```
'<thunt:sendSubscriptionResult xmlns:thunt="http://example.com/thunt" status="alreadySubscribed">Hello, World</thunt:sendSubscriptionResult>'
```

**HTTParty**

```
{"thunt:sendSubscriptionResult"=>"Hello, World"}
```

As you can see, HTTParty has stripped all of the element's attributes, and has put only the text node in the resulting Hash

Is this a bug in HTTParty or am I doing something wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: I've had nothing but trouble with XML and HTTParty so I'd love to see a solid answer to this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out my post on the github issue for a resolution to your problem. http://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/issues/#issue/14

Comment: i should add that i see no reason why it should be so complicated and unnecessarily cluttered to get a coherent hash out of the xml..

Answer (score 0):

I would go ahead and post your problems on the issues page for their Github project.

http://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/issues

It already looks like there are some issues surrounding some XML issues.  But it's definitely the best way to communicate directly with the developers and to provide them feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood, httparty currently uses multi_xml for XML parsing.  multi_xml will use, based on the speed of the available parsing gem: Ox, LibXML, Nokogiri, REXML.  That is, it will choose Ox first, if you have it installed.  You can also specify which parser to use.

There were some bugs recently resolved in multi_xml, particularly with regard to arrays.

I suggest you point bundler to the GitHub repo to get the very latest version of multi_xml, in your Gemfile like this:

```
gem 'multi_xml', :git => 'https://github.com/sferik/multi_xml'
gem 'ox'
gem 'httparty'
```

Then where you are going to use httparty (for example, in your Sinatra server) you would do this:

```
require 'bundler/setup'
```

Note that with this setup, multi_xml will not show up in your "gem list" output, but it will work.